# Store pointers to member function in the map

Tags: c++, design-patterns, callback

I'd like to map string to an instance member functions, and store each mapping in the map.

What is the clean way of doing something like that?

```
class  MyClass
{
   //........
   virtual double GetX();
   virtual double GetSomethingElse();
   virtual double GetT();
   virtual double GetRR();
   //........
};


class Processor
{
 private:
      typedef double (MyClass::*MemFuncGetter)();
      static map<std::string, MemFuncGetter> descrToFuncMap;

 public:
        static void Initialize();
        void Process(Myclass m, string);
};

void Processor::Initialize()
{

     descrToFuncMap["X"]=&MyClass::GetX;
     descrToFuncMap["SomethingElse"]=&MyClass::GetSomethingElse;
     descrToFuncMap["RR"]=&MyClass::GetRR;
     descrToFuncMap["T"]=&MyClass::GetT;
};
void Processor::Process(MyClass ms, const std::string& key)
{
     map<std::string, Getter>::iterator found=descrToFuncMap.find(key);
     if(found!=descrToFuncMap.end())
     {
        MemFuncGetter memFunc=found->second;
        double dResult=(ms).*memFunc();    
        std::cout<<"Command="<<key<<", and result="<<result<<std::end;      
      }
 }
```

let me know if you see a problem with this approach and what are common idioms for that?

**Perhaps, I should use if-else-if statement chain, given that I have a limited number of member functions, instead of a confusing map of func pointers**

BTW, I found some of the useful info here in the [c++-faq-lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html)

Comment: Actually I think the map is nicer than an if-else chain. It gives you a nice hook for storing other meta-information later if the need arises -- just expand the value type from function pointer to a struct containing a function pointer plus whatever other info you need.

Comment: I agree, looks better, though harder to understand for a less experienced developer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks fine to me, but for the fact that `descrToFuncMap` needs to be declared `static` if you intend to initialise it from inside the static function `Initialize()`.

If you want to make sure that `Initialize()` gets called, and gets called just once, you can use the Singleton pattern.  Basically, if you aren't doing multithreading, that just means wrapping `descrToFuncMap` inside its own class (called say `FuncMap`) with a private constructor that calls `Initialize()`.  Then you add a `static` local variable of type `FuncMap` to `Processor::Process()` -- because the variable is `static`, it persists and is only initialised once.

Example code (I now realise that `friend` isn't really necessary here):

```
class Processor {
private:
    typedef double (MyClass::*MemFuncGetter)();

    class FuncMap {
    public:
        FuncMap() {
            descrToFuncMap["X"]=&MyClass::GetX;
            descrToFuncMap["SomethingElse"]=&MyClass::GetSomethingElse;
            descrToFuncMap["RR"]=&MyClass::GetRR;
            descrToFuncMap["T"]=&MyClass::GetT;
        }

        // Of course you could encapsulate this, but its hardly worth
        // the bother since the whole class is private anyway.
        map<std::string, MemFuncGetter> descrToFuncMap;
    };

public:
    void Process(Myclass m, string);
};

void Processor::Process(MyClass ms, const std::string& key) {
    static FuncMap fm;      // Only gets initialised on first call
    map<std::string, Getter>::iterator found=fm.descrToFuncMap.find(key);
    if(found!=fm.descrToFuncMap.end()) {
        MemFuncGetter memFunc=found->second;
        double dResult=(ms).*memFunc();    
        std::cout<<"Command="<<key<<", and result="<<result<<std::end;      
    }
}
```

This is not the "true" Singleton pattern as different functions could create their own, separate instances of `FuncMap`, but it's enough for what you need.  For "true" Singleton, you would declare `FuncMap`'s constructor private and add a static method, say `getInstance()`, which defined the one-and-only instance as a `static` variable and returned a reference to that.  `Processor::Process()` would then use this with

```
FuncMap& fm = FuncMap::getInstance();
```

Comment: yea it is static (fixed it). I like the idea of a private friend class. Would you demonstrate it with an example? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd change

```
void Processor::Process(MyClass ms, std::string key)
```

to

```
void Processor::Process(const MyClass& ms, const std::string& key)
```

Don't see any bad side effect for now. Probably with boost::function as a map value it will be easier in the future.

Comment: well yea, obviously I would pass string as a const to reference. My question is perhaps, I should use if-statement chain given that I have a limited number of member functions instead of a confusing map of func pointers

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using 'virtual' if you are using maps of function pointers. In this context, using 'virtual' keyword will not help much. For example

```
descrToFuncMap["X"]=&MyClass::GetX;
```

will always call '*MyClass::GetX*' function even if *GetX* is overridden by the derived class of MyClass.

Usually you won't have large number of functions in class, rather than using map you can create simple struct array and use a for loop. If the number of functions are small, there won't be any big performance difference in map and array. Something similar to code below will work

```
class  MyClass
{
   //........
   double GetX();
   double GetSomethingElse();
   double GetT();
   double GetRR();
   //........
};

typedef double (MyClass::*MemFuncGetter)();

struct FuncTable
{
    const char* m_pFuncName;
    MemFuncGetter m_pFuncPtr;
};

class Processor
{          
 public:
        void Process(Myclass& m, string);
};

static FuncTable descrToFuncMap[]
{
    { "X",  &MyClass::GetX},
    { "SomethingElse", &MyClass::GetSomethingElse },
    { "RR", &MyClass::GetRR},
    { "T", &MyClass::GetT}
};

void Processor::Process(MyClass& ms, const std::string& key)
{
    int functablesize = sizeof(descrToFuncMap)/sizeof(descrToFuncMap[0])

    for(int i=0; i< functablesize; ++i)
    {   
        if( strcmp(key.c_str(), descrToFuncMap[i].m_pFuncName)==0)
        {
            MemFuncGetter memFunc=descrToFuncMap[i].m_pFuncPtr;
            double dResult=(ms).*memFunc();    
            std::cout<<"Command="<<key<<"result="<<result<<std::end;
            break;
        }
    }     
 }
```

Comment: Why doesn't it call an overriden function?