# How can Binder2nd objects that store pointers to member functions be used in a map?

Tags: c++, stl

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630920/store-pointers-to-member-function-in-the-map). I need to store pointers to member functions in the map. The member functions takes an argument, which has to binded by a specific value while constructing the map. How do i do that? Should map have a binder2nd object as its value.

Eg:

```
enum { FOO, BAR };

exMap["foo"]  = bind2nd(&classA::Func, FOO);
```

I don't know how to declare this map.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you want to achieve?
For what purpose you want to store those things?
It is not clear why you use map. What will be the asociation of the elements?
In oterh words, what you want to be your keys in map?

Comment: I have a func with a switch case on the enum. The enum string is passed as a command line argument, which i lookup in a map and call the function binded with the enum translation of the string

Comment: fine, I have posted an answer taking into account details above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that works using [Boost.Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/function.html):

```
#include "boost/function.hpp"
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Foo {
    void bar(int x) {
        std::cout << "bar called with x=" << x << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    std::map<int, boost::function<void (Foo*)> > m;

    m[1] = std::bind2nd(std::mem_fun(&Foo::bar), 3);

    m[1](&foo);

    return 0;
}
```

Apparently this is not possible with `binder2nd`, because it is not default-constructible, which is a requirement for the values of an `std::map`.

Since you cannot use Boost, you will have to write your own binder.

Comment: I cant use boost. Sorry forgot to mention.

Comment: @Vivek: Then you will have to write your own binder, because `binder2nd` cannot be used in an `std::map`, since it is not default-constructible.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `bind2nd` you could do that manually with `std::pair`.  An Example:

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

enum { FOO, BAR };

class classA{
public:
    void Func(int){}
};

// define classAMemFn
typedef void (classA::*classAMemFn)(int);
// define element
typedef std::pair<classAMemFn, int> XElement;

typedef std::map<std::string, XElement> XMap;

void setup(XMap& xmap){
    xmap["FOO"]=std::make_pair(&classA::Func,FOO);
    xmap["BAR"]=std::make_pair(&classA::Func,BAR);
}

void Caller(XMap& xmap, const std::string& key, classA& obj){
    XMap::iterator it=xmap.find(key);
    if (it!=xmap.end()) {
        XElement e=it->second;
        (obj.*e.first)(e.second);
    }
}
```

The `setup` function 'binds' pointers to member functions and a parameter to a string key.

The `Caller` function encapsulates the messy business of finding the pair in the map and performing the call.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from your comment to the question you need a mapping from string to enum and then you want to call a function with enum value.
If so, why you are complicating things with binders?

You can simply do something like:

```
// Initialize your map with appropriate string -> enum mappings.
```

and

```
callYourFunction(yourMap[yourStringFromInput]);
```

The type of the map would be:

```
std::map<std::string, YourEnumType> yourMap;
```

And function’s prototype:

```
SomeReturnType callYourFunction(YourEnumType e);
```

That’s it, no more binders ;)